Expected position of squeezed state
I want to compute the expected position $\langle \alpha,r | x | \alpha, r \rangle$ of a squeezed state defined as
$$
| \alpha, r\rangle = S(r)|\alpha\rangle\ ,
$$
where $S(r)$ is the operator
$$
S(r) = e^{\frac{1}{2}r(a^2 - a^{\dagger 2})} \ .
$$
However, I am having problems finding the expression for the squeezed state itself because of the exponential acting on the coherent state $|\alpha\rangle$. How would one work with that exponential?

Operator exponentials are defined via the Taylor expansion of exp. You can compute the action of $S(r)$ on the coherent state given that you know how $a$ and its adjoint act on it. If you only know how the two operators act on some particular basis states, then you expand the coherent state in that basis and work from there.
